MAUI CollectionView not updating when item properties change in ObservableCollection
I'm developing an application in .NET MAUI where I display a list of products in a shopping cart using a CollectionView bound to an ObservableCollection. I've implemented INotifyPropertyChanged in my model using [ObservableProperty] from CommunityToolkit.Mvvm. However, when I execute the IncreaseProduct command, the UI does not reflect any changes. To see the updates, I have to leave the current screen and return.
Here is my XAML code for the view:
<StackLayout Grid.Row="0">
    <Label Text="{Binding TotalProducts, StringFormat='Total Products: {0}'}"/>
    <Label Text="{Binding TotalSum, StringFormat='SubTotal: {0:C2}'}"/>
</StackLayout>

<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding ShopingCartsList}"
                Grid.Row="1"
                Margin="0,40,0,0">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Frame Margin="0,10,0,0" Padding="5">
                <StackLayout>
                    <Label Text="{Binding ProductName}" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Qty, StringFormat='Quantity: {0}'}" Margin="0,10,0,0"/>
                    <Label Text="{Binding UnitPrice, StringFormat='Unit Price: {0:C2}'}"/>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Total, StringFormat='Total: {0:C2}'}"/>
                    <!-- ButtonView contains buttons to increase/decrease quantity -->
                    <views:ButtonView />
                </StackLayout>
            </Frame>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>


My ShoppingListViewModel inherits from BaseViewModel, which in turn inherits from ObservableObject.
public partial class ShoppingListViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public ShoppingListViewModel()
    {
        ShopingCartsList = new ObservableCollection<ShopingCart>();
        _ = GetProducts();
    }

    [ObservableProperty]
    private ObservableCollection<ShopingCart> shopingCartsList;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private int totalProducts;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private double totalSum;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private int idShopingCar;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private int productName;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private int qty; 

    [ObservableProperty]
    private int total;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private int idProduct;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private int unitPrice;

    public async Task GetProducts()
    {
        var objList = await App.ShopingCartRepo.GetItemsAsync();
        ShopingCartsList = new ObservableCollection<ShopingCart>(objList);
        UpdateTotals();
    }

    private void UpdateTotals()
    {
        TotalSum = ShopingCartsList.Sum(x => x.Total);
        TotalProducts = ShopingCartsList.Count;
    }

    [RelayCommand]
    public async Task IncreaseProduct(ShopingCart selectedProduct)
    {
        var searchProduct = ShopingCartsList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.IdProduct == selectedProduct.IdProduct);

        if (searchProduct != null)
        {
            searchProduct.Qty += 1;
            searchProduct.Total = searchProduct.Qty * searchProduct.UnitPrice;

            // Diagnostic log
            Console.WriteLine($"Product updated: Qty={searchProduct.Qty}, Total={searchProduct.Total}");

            UpdateTotals();
            await App.ShopingCartRepo.SaveItemAsync(searchProduct);
            await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Note", "Product Updated", "Ok");
        }
    }
}


How can I make the CollectionView and the labels bound to TotalSum and TotalProducts update the UI immediately when the properties change? Am I missing something about property change notifications or data binding in MAUI?

Since you use the Model-View-ViewModel (MVVM) pattern, the ProductName, Qty, UnitPrice Property should be placed in the ShopingCart model instead of the ViewModel.
Here is ShopingCart model,
public partial class ShopingCart : ObservableObject
{
    ...

    [NotifyPropertyChangedFor(nameof(Total))]
    [ObservableProperty]
    int qty;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedFor(nameof(Total))]
    [ObservableProperty]
    float unitPrice;


    public float Total
    {
        get
        {
            return Qty * UnitPrice;
        }
    }
}

The Total should be equal to Qty * UnitPrice. So, the Total should be changed whenever Qty or UnitPrice changes. Thus, we may use NotifyPropertyChangedFor attribute.
That would be easier for the Command because you don't have to count the Total value in it again.
   [RelayCommand]
   public async Task IncreaseProduct(ShopingCart selectedProduct)
   {
       var searchProduct = ShopingCartsList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.IdProduct == selectedProduct.IdProduct);

       if (searchProduct != null)
       {
           searchProduct.Qty += 1;
           //searchProduct.Total = searchProduct.Qty * searchProduct.UnitPrice;

          ...
       }
   }

One more thing is the UpdateTotals method,
    private void UpdateTotals()
    {
        TotalSum = ShopingCartsList.Sum(x => x.Total);
        //TotalProducts = ShopingCartsList.Count;
        TotalProducts = ShopingCartsList.Sum(x => x.Qty);
    }

TotalProducts could be counted by sum the Qty of all the Items.

Whilst CommunityToolkit.Mvvm can save you the NotifyProperty change, it is not needed for ShopingCartsList, TotalSum and TotalProducts. Which have 1 liner definitions, e.g.
public ObservableCollection<ShopingCart> shopingCartsList {get;} = new();
// public int TotalProducts => ShopingCartsList.Count; // commented out, see direct bind workaround
public double TotalSum => ShopingCartsList.Sum(x => x.Total);

and, even, we can eliminate TotalProducts property since you can bind directly to ShopingCartsList.Count in XAML:
<Label Text="{Binding ShopingCartsList.Count, StringFormat='Total Products: {0}'}"/>

It's not obvious how you're updating ShopingCartsList, but, once you do, you need to call:
// OnPropertyChanged(nameof(TotalProduts)); // comment out, see direct bind workaround
OnPropertyChanged(nameof(TotalSum));


Hi Stephen, thanks for the corrections. I've applied them, but I'm still having the same issue. The value of Text="{Binding TotalSum}" continues to reset when exiting the app or when navigating to another view, even after updating and using:
await App.ShoppingCartRepo.UpdateItem(searchProduct);
OnPropertyChanged(nameof(TotalSum));
Here’s a small snippet of the code :Code Snippet
